# C threading, passing a mutex to a thread with a shared buffer

Tags: c, thread-safety, pthreads, buffer, mutex

I have a C program where I wish to share a buffer between 2 threads. I also would like it to be thread safe so I want to pass a mutex as well. But since I can only pass 1 pointer to the thread I am trying to copy the mutex into the buffer, sending it and having the thread pull out the mutex and then use the buffer.

When the thread gets the mutex out, it has lost connection to the main thread's mutex.
This is a silly example, but I would like the thread to lock the mutex and have the main thread get blocked, just to prove that this works. Currently the main thread goes on forever.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

#define BUFF 1024

void *func(void *buffer) {
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    memcpy(&lock, buffer, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //example
    // do stuff with buffer
}

int main() {
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("error in mutex init\n");
        return 1;
    }

    void *sharedBuffer = calloc(1, BUFF);
    memcpy(sharedBuffer, &lock, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t));
    pthread_t handle;

    pthread_create(&handle, NULL, func, sharedBuffer);
    while (true) {
        if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&lock) == 0) {
            printf("in main\n");
            if (*(int*)sharedBuffer != 0) {
                //do stuff with shared buffer
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a proper way to share a buffer and mutex between threads is C? All the ways I have tried one of the 2 loses its connection to main. Any thoughts are appreciated (except if you say to use globals)

Comment: Remove all `pthread_mutex_t lock;` from the various _function scoped_ variables. Put a _single_ definition at the top of the file as a _global_ scope variable. All of these definitions end up as separate instances in various places in various per-thread stacks. Don't forget to init it in `main` with (e.g.) `pthread_mutex_init`

Comment: Use a struct that holds the mutex and buffer. Or a completely different design that doesn't try to share data between threads.

Comment: Thank you! the struct toally worked.

Comment: @CraigEstey apparently you didn't read my post. I don't want to use global variables. Global variables are bad practice and the whole point is to find the right way to do it

Comment: Global variables are _not_ "bad practice" when used sparingly. Especially, for a "lock the world". You didn't see that function scoped vars wouldn't work. So, start simply. Crawl before you walk. Get the global version working first.  Then, you could come with a "per buffer" locking scheme [using a `struct`]

Comment: Pthreads mutexes should not be copied.  Undefined behavior arises from using a mutex object that was not, itself, initalized via either `pthread_mutex_init()` or the static initializer.  You certainly cannot rely on a copy of a mutex being equivalent to the original for synchronization purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use a struct that holds the mutex and buffer.

You *don't* need to have a struct which holds the mutex; you need a struct which holds a *pointer* to a mutex.

Here is an example:

```
struct Arg {
  pthread_mutex_t *lock;
  char buf[BUFF];
};
```

You would initialize this struct like so (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
int main()
{
  pthread_mutex_t lock;
  pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

  struct Arg *arg = calloc(1, sizeof(*arg));
  arg->lock = &lock;

  pthread_t handle;
  pthread_create(&handle, NULL, func, arg);
...
```

In the thread function, do this:

```
void *func(void *buffer)
{
  struct Arg *arg = (struct Arg *)buffer;

  pthread_mutex_lock(arg->lock);  // locks the same mutex as main.
  ...
```